# "Sorglich" im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch

Tags: word-usage, usage, vocabulary

Gesehen heute Morgen auf einem LKW:

> Spedition xxx: Sorglich und sanft

Ist denn *sorglich* noch ein akzeptiertes Wort im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch? Benutzt das jemand? Oder hatte die Spedition nur einen schlechten Werbetexter?

Comment: Laut [Wortschatz Leipzig](http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/cgi-portal/de/wort_www?site=208&Wort_id=71207780) ist das Wort 5 Häufigkeitsstufen unter *pfleglich*, das ist immerhin noch 1/16 von dessen Häufigkeit. Mangels substanzieller Gründe habe ich Schließung weil meinungsbasiert vorgeschlagen.

Comment: Und es war kein Wortspiel mit dem `xxx`-Teil?

Comment: Nee. Das xxx war irgendwas ganz Banales - Wie "Schulze" oder so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ich kannte als Muttersprachler das Wort nicht und musste es googeln.

Laut Duden bedeutet [sorglich](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sorglich) *fürsorglich* oder *sorgfältig*. Das Wort kommt allerdings selten vor und der Gebrauch ist "veraltend" (= d.h. das Wort kommt gegenwärtig langsam außer Gebrauch).

Ich vermute, dass der Slogan der Speditionsfirma einfach zu einer Zeit entstanden ist, als das Wort noch im allgemeinen Sprachgebrauch vorhanden war.